# Delete selected text not working with customSelectionActionModeCallback in Edit Text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a customSelectionActionModeCallback for my EditText (for my custom text formatting options)

Now when I select some text in my EditText and try to delete that using back press key (aka Delete key), nothing happens, only the cursor is set back to the first position in the EditText.

But if I am deleting the characters one by one (not selecting the text at first) -> then everything works as expected.

I have tried disabling my customSelectionActionModeCallback, just to check if it works fine without this, and it does.

So how can I have my customSelectionActionModeCallback with these standard functions like delete selected text on back key pressed?